# SQL query no using indexes properly

Tags: mysql, sql, join, indexing

Having a problem with one of my SQL queries. This is my query:

```
explain 
SELECT DISTINCT profiles.hoofdrubriek, profiles.plaats, profiles.bedrijfsnaam, profiles.gemeente, profiles.bedrijfsslogan, profiles.straatnaam, profiles.huisnummer, profiles.postcode, profiles.telefoonnummer, profiles.fax, profiles.email, profiles.website, profiles.bedrijfslogo 
FROM profiles 
LEFT JOIN profile_subrubriek ON profiles.ID=profile_subrubriek.profile_id 
LEFT JOIN rubrieken ON profile_subrubriek.subrubriek_id=rubrieken.ID  
WHERE (
    rubrieken.rubriek = 'Pedicurepraktijken' OR 
    profiles.hoofdrubriek = 'Pedicurepraktijken'
) 
ORDER BY profiles.grade DESC, profiles.bedrijfsnaam
```

The 'OR' operator in this piece of the query is causing troubles:

```
rubrieken.rubriek = 'Pedicurepraktijken' OR profiles.hoofdrubriek = 'Pedicurepraktijken'
```

I have indexes applied on all my tables which function properly if I take out one of the two pieces of the above line of code. Combining them with an OR operator causes it to break down and it refuses to use the index I have applied on the 'hoofdrubriek' column in my profiles table. Below the layouts of my relevant tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `profiles` (
 `ID` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 ......
 `hoofdrubriek` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
...


 `timestamp` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `meerderevestigingen` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `grade` int(5) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
 KEY `IDX_TIMESTAMP` (`timestamp`),
 KEY `IDX_NIEUW` (`nieuw`),
 KEY `IDX_HOOFDRUBRIEK` (`hoofdrubriek`),
 KEY `bedrijfsnaam` (`bedrijfsnaam`),
 KEY `grade` (`grade`),
 KEY `gemeente` (`gemeente`),
 KEY `plaats` (`plaats`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8


CREATE TABLE `rubrieken` (
 `ID` mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `rubriek` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
 UNIQUE KEY `rubriek` (`rubriek`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1905 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8


CREATE TABLE `profile_subrubriek` (
 `profile_id` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 `subrubriek_id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`subrubriek_id`,`profile_id`),
 KEY `profile_id` (`profile_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Of course I could solve the problem with a UNION DISTICT, thus combining the two different queries, but I don't think that should be the way to go..

Comment: is there any performance problems? sometimes SQL doesn't use indexes because it doesn't have to

Comment: What Database are you using?  MYSQL?

Comment: I'm indeed using MYSQL. Not using the index means it scans about 600000+ rows, it makes it annoyingly slow and probably uses too much resources.

Comment: Have you tried using the [USE INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/index-hints.html) hint? I still suspect that UNION is the way to go.

Comment: @GarethD, yes I did. No error message, so the Hint should have been OK, but still wasn't using the index. Union will solve the issue, but shouldn't there be a cleaner solution? What's the underlying cause I'm missing here..

Comment: I think if you specifically want to know the steps the optimiser is taking to determine that a table scan is more efficient than using the indexes you may need to ask on http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if an `or` is causing a problem, then the simplest solution is to break the query into two pieces and put them together using `union` (in your case, because of the `distinct`).  Rectifying the `where` clause using an index is going to probably be impossible, because it references two different columns:

```
SELECT p.hoofdrubriek, p.plaats, p.bedrijfsnaam, p.gemeente, p.bedrijfsslogan, profiles.straatnaam, 
       p.huisnummer, profiles.postcode, p.telefoonnummer, p.fax, p.email, p.website, p.bedrijfslogo, 
       p.grade
FROM profiles p 
LEFT JOIN profile_subrubriek ON p.ID=profile_subrubriek.profile_id 
LEFT JOIN rubrieken ON profile_subrubriek.subrubriek_id=rubrieken.ID  
WHERE rubrieken.rubriek = 'Pedicurepraktijken' 
union 
SELECT p.hoofdrubriek, p.plaats, p.bedrijfsnaam, p.gemeente, p.bedrijfsslogan, profiles.straatnaam, 
       p.huisnummer, profiles.postcode, p.telefoonnummer, p.fax, p.email, p.website, p.bedrijfslogo, 
       p.grade
FROM profiles p 
LEFT JOIN profile_subrubriek ON p.ID=profile_subrubriek.profile_id 
LEFT JOIN rubrieken ON profile_subrubriek.subrubriek_id=rubrieken.ID  
WHERE p.hoofdrubriek = 'Pedicurepraktijken'
ORDER BY grade DESC, bedrijfsnaam;
```

I added `grade` into the `select` clause so it could be  used by the `order by`.

Comment: I think OP was asking if there is a way other than `UNION`.

Comment: Thanks for your time and effector Gordon, however, Vatev is right. Under the 'creat-code' of the tables, I stated that there should be a better way to go than UNION, is there not?

Comment: @Gordon, after some time of searching and trial-and-error, I've decided to go with the UNION. I was hoping to find a cleaner way, but it's effective! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I think Gordon is right about using UNION, but you can make the UNION much more efficient:

In the first query below, since you are only referring to the `profiles` table, you can remove the joins, they will only serve to cause duplicates that subsequently need to be removed. Then in the second, you can change the JOINs from OUTER to INNER, since you are referring to a field in the outer most table in the where clause you are stating there has to be a match. Then by adding a clause to remove values picked up by the first part of the union you will have less records to sort and remove duplicates from.

```
SELECT  profiles.hoofdrubriek, 
        profiles.plaats, 
        profiles.bedrijfsnaam, 
        profiles.gemeente, 
        profiles.bedrijfsslogan, 
        profiles.straatnaam, 
        profiles.huisnummer, 
        profiles.postcode, 
        profiles.telefoonnummer, 
        profiles.fax, 
        profiles.email, 
        profiles.website, 
        profiles.bedrijfslogo,
        profiles.grade
FROM    profiles   
WHERE   profiles.hoofdrubriek = 'Pedicurepraktijken'
UNION
SELECT  profiles.hoofdrubriek, 
        profiles.plaats, 
        profiles.bedrijfsnaam, 
        profiles.gemeente, 
        profiles.bedrijfsslogan, 
        profiles.straatnaam, 
        profiles.huisnummer, 
        profiles.postcode, 
        profiles.telefoonnummer, 
        profiles.fax, 
        profiles.email, 
        profiles.website, 
        profiles.bedrijfslogo,
        profiles.grade
FROM    profiles 
        INNER JOIN profile_subrubriek 
            ON profiles.ID=profile_subrubriek.profile_id 
        INNER JOIN rubrieken 
            ON profile_subrubriek.subrubriek_id=rubrieken.ID  
WHERE   rubrieken.rubriek = 'Pedicurepraktijken' 
AND     profiles.hoofdrubriek != 'Pedicurepraktijken'
ORDER BY grade DESC, bedrijfsnaam;
```

My knowledge of the inner workings of the MySQL optimisier is hazy to say the least, but my understanding is that the underlying cause is that MySQL does not use the index because it needs to scan the whole table anyway to check for the other predicate (`rubrieken.rubriek = 'Pedicurepraktijken'`). I think you are expecting that the optimiser will do implicitly is what the UNION does explicitly. (I think) because of the OUTER JOINs and the OR, the optimiser is unable to accurately determine how many rows of `profiles` it is going to have to read to find a match in `rubrieken` OR in profiles, it cannot determine accurately if an index seek will be more efficient than a table scan, and opts for the table scan.

This is not unique to MySQL, it is not uncommon accross all DMBS for it to be more efficient to use `UNION` instead of `OR`.

Rearranging the queries as I have gives the optimiser a much better chance of using the right indexes (I suspect without the `USE INDEX` hint too, but I haven't tested).

Answer (score 0):

I would switching to InnoDB a try since they are index-organized tables.
All data of your linking table `profile_subrubriek` would be in the clustered index when using InnoDB.

Same for the table `rubrieken` when you switch from surrogate primary key to the natural primary key `rubrieken`. Since that is a one-column-table then it's existence is at least questionable.

So I would eliminate the table `rubrieken`.

I would it do this way:

```
CREATE TABLE `profiles` (
 `ID` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 ......
 `hoofdrubriek` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
...


 `timestamp` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `meerderevestigingen` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `grade` int(5) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
 KEY `IDX_TIMESTAMP` (`timestamp`),
 KEY `IDX_NIEUW` (`nieuw`),
 KEY `IDX_HOOFDRUBRIEK` (`hoofdrubriek`),
 KEY `bedrijfsnaam` (`bedrijfsnaam`),
 KEY `grade` (`grade`),
 KEY `gemeente` (`gemeente`),
 KEY `plaats` (`plaats`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `profile_rubriek` (
 `profile_id` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 `rubriek` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`profile_id`,`rubriek`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

The query would be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT profiles.hoofdrubriek, profiles.plaats, profiles.bedrijfsnaam, profiles.gemeente, profiles.bedrijfsslogan, profiles.straatnaam, profiles.huisnummer, profiles.postcode, profiles.telefoonnummer, profiles.fax, profiles.email, profiles.website, profiles.bedrijfslogo 
FROM profiles 
LEFT JOIN profile_rubriek ON profiles.ID=profile_rubriek.profile_id 
WHERE (
    profile_rubriek.rubriek = 'Pedicurepraktijken' OR 
    profiles.hoofdrubriek = 'Pedicurepraktijken'
) 
ORDER BY profiles.grade DESC, profiles.bedrijfsnaam
```